# Moving from one host to another—possible to keep email?

Tags: email, hosting

I am moving a website from one host to another. In this account are two email addresses, used via IMAP. Is it possible to keep the messages in these accounts and transfer them to an entirely different server?

Apologies if this is on the wrong site.

Comment: Export/Import seems like the least fuss to me.

Comment: Download email through IMAP then upload copies of emails to new account through IMAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download an E-mail client (such as [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/EN/thunderbird/)) and connect to all of your accounts (both old and new) through IMAP.

You can then copy (or move) all of your e-mail from your old accounts' inboxes to your new accounts' inboxes (or any other folders of your choice.) [This article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Importing_and_exporting_your_mail#Migrating_messages_using_a_mail_server) outlines the procedure in Thunderbird.

Comment: Did this, but with Mail.app. Just archived the mailbox, updating the account settings, imported the mailbox archive, and then dragged the messages from the archive back into the inbox. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use IMAP accounts synchronization tools e.g. [isync](http://isync.sourceforge.net/)

Isync web page list a few more available alternatives for *IMAP to IMAP* or *IMAP to maildir* ( IMAP to maildir + maildir to IMAP) synchronizations.